# No environment variables are set after sourcing. Vagrant provisioning with Ansible and shell

Tags: shell, vagrant, ansible, vagrant-provision

I append both `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `$HOME/.bashrc` with variables by using Ansible.

After Ansible finished, the two files look like the following.

In `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```sh
...
export VAR1="some text comes here"
...
```

In `$HOME/.bashrc`:

```sh
...
export VAR2="other text comes here"
...
```

So, Ansible does its job perfectly.

The shell script in Vagrantfile, that runs after Ansible finishes:

```rb
$init = <<-SCRIPT
whoami
echo $HOME
cat /etc/bash.bashrc
cat $HOME/.bashrc
source /etc/bash.bashrc
source $HOME/.bashrc
echo "VAR1 :: $VAR1"
echo "VAR2 :: $VAR2"
SCRIPT

config.vm.provision :init, type: :shell, inline: $init, privileged: false
```

Even though the two variables are set in the two files and then both files are sourced the output is:

```sh
vagrant
/home/vagrant
---> /etc/bash.bashrc contains the export
---> $HOME/.bashrc contains the export as well
VAR1 ::
VAR2 ::
```

As we see the two variables are not set and provides empty string.

I tried it with `$HOME/.profile`, but the same result.

Do you have any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enough that `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `source $HOME/.bashrc` contain the variable assignment. The variable assignment must actually have a chance to be executed.

If you look at the source of both scripts (examples below from Debian), they contain lines which break the execution when invoked in a non-interactive shell:

- `/etc/bash.bashrc`

  ```
  # If not running interactively, don't do anything
  [ -z "$PS1" ] && return
  ```
- `$HOME/.bashrc`

  ```
  # If not running interactively, don't do anything
  case $- in
      *i*) ;;
        *) return;;
  esac
  ```

So even though you explicitly source those files, if you insert the lines `export VAR1="some text comes here"` or `export VAR2="other text comes here"` after those conditions, they will never be executed as the provisioning script runs as non-interactive shell.

You don't actually show how you insert the variable assignment lines, but you say you "*append*" them. If you use Ansible's `lineinfile` module, you can add the `insertbefore` parameter to ensure these lines are placed before the script exits.